# C# Entity Framework LINQ Check if Context is Detached before RemoveRange with List of Objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am writing a LINQ to SQL to do a `RemoveRange`. The following is working.

```
ctx.Table1Set.AttachRange(records);
ctx.Table1Set.RemoveRange(records);
```

I have to do `AttachRange` or my `RemoveRange` will throw an exception that it does not exists in the `ObjectManager`.

I would like to check if my ctx is attached or not attached with the parameter, LIST of records which is a list of two fields, ID and CODE

```
1  1001
2  1002 
3  1003
```

I researched on other post using the following code

```
var entry = context.Entry(ug);
if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    context.MY_GROUPS.Attach(ug);
}
```

but this is for one object and not a list of objects.

Is there a way to check the context state with a list?

If I have a `List<Table1>` aka list of records,

How can I check if the context, ctx, not attached with a LIST of objects?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of the reputation requirement, but one way to debug this is to try a foreach on newrecords and then try .remove() on the record inside a try catch.